# Cut Pandas dataframe based on unique values per column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to cut pandas data frame with duplicated values in a column into separate data frames.
So from this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'block': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'd': [{'A': 1}, {'B': 'A'}, {'B': 3}, {'C': 'Z'}]})

  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B': 'A'}
2     B  {'B':  3 }
3     C  {'C': 'Z'}
```

I would like to achieve two separate data frames:

```
    df1:
  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B': 'A'}
2     C  {'C': 'Z'}

    df2:
  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B':  3 }
2     C  {'C': 'Z'}
```

Another example:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'block': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                       'd': [{'A': 1}, {'B': 'A'}, {'B': 3}, {'C': 'Z'}, {'C': 10}]})
```

Result:

```
  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B': 'A'}
2     C  {'C': 'Z'}

  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B': 'A'}
2     C  {'C': 10 }

  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B':  3 }
2     C  {'C': 'Z'}

  block           d
0     A  {'A':  1 }
1     B  {'B':  3 }
2     C  {'C': 10 }
```

I should add that I want to preserve the order of the column 'block'.

I tried pandas explode and itertools package but without good results. If someone knows how to solve this - please help.

Comment: if you have the `block` and `d` list then instead of performing operation on pandas dataframe, why don't you use the `list` to create the dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, `iterrows` and `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

prods = []
for _, d in df.groupby("block"):
    prods.append([s for _, s in d.iterrows()])
dfs = [pd.concat(ss, axis=1).T for ss in product(*prods)]
print(dfs)
```

Output:

```
[  block           d
 0     A    {'A': 1}
 1     B  {'B': 'A'}
 3     C  {'C': 'Z'},
   block           d
 0     A    {'A': 1}
 2     B    {'B': 3}
 3     C  {'C': 'Z'}]
```

Output for second sample `df`:

```
[  block           d
 0     A    {'A': 1}
 1     B  {'B': 'A'}
 3     C  {'C': 'Z'},
   block           d
 0     A    {'A': 1}
 1     B  {'B': 'A'}
 4     C   {'C': 10},
   block           d
 0     A    {'A': 1}
 2     B    {'B': 3}
 3     C  {'C': 'Z'},
   block          d
 0     A   {'A': 1}
 2     B   {'B': 3}
 4     C  {'C': 10}]
```